# Python Poetry build not packaging cli file

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-click

I created this project with the following structure:

```
repo_dir
 - module_name
 - cli.py
 - pyproject.toml
```

The `cli.py` file has code with functions using [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) to call functions within the directory `module_name`.

The `pyproject.toml` file has the section `tool.poetry.scripts` to define the cli `.py` file:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
cli = 'cli:main'
```

Within the file `cli.py` I have this:

```py
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    ...


def main():
    cli(obj={})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However when I use `poetry build` and install the `.whl` file in an environment it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cooh", line 5, in <module>
    from cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli'
```

I think for some reason when I use `poetry build` it is not packaging the `cli.py` file and in a new environment in a different directory this file does not exist hence it raises this error.

---

**How to package a CLI using Poetry and Click?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution I found is to move the `cli.py` file into the `module_name` directory:

```
repo_dir
 - module_name
   - cli.py
 - pyproject.toml
```

Then change the `pyproject.toml` to reflect the new structure:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
cli = 'module_name.cli:main'
```